# Cakephp Model save and update without modifying `created` and `modified` fields

Tags: cakephp

Can any body tell how to save and update database table using Model save function without modifying the `created` and `modified` fields in cakephp 2.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don’t want the **modified** field to be updated when saving some data add

```
'modified' => false
```

to your $data array

Ref: [Saving Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

Hope it helps

Example:

```
$this->request->data['YourModel']['modified'] = false;
```

Comment: @matheusvmbruno i've added an example, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that setting 'modified' to false will stop the modified date from being saved. However, I have found that this causes the Save call to fail without any indication of what is wrong. Using unset on the modified value seems to work, however.

```
unset( $this->request->data['YourModel']['modified'] );
```

Documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array

Comment: A link to the documentation please?

Comment: Link to documentation (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array) added to my answer. See the tip that reads:
If you don’t want the modified field to be automatically updated when saving some data add 'modified' => false to your $data array

Comment: Not setting it would actually result in the opposite behavior: Modified will be updated. Thus this answer is incorrect.